# msaccess form property 'min max buttons' not working

Tags: ms-access-2007

All my forms are displaying full screen with only a close form button. I have set form properties:

```
  Min Max Buttons = Both Enabled
  Control Box = Yes
  Border Style = Sizeable
```

I've tried a DoCmd.Restore to no effect.
This seems to be a perennial problem with Access but how to solve it?

Comment: This is not normal. Try creating a new empty database, then import all objects from the old.

Answer (score 0):

look under Access Options/Current Database. The Document Windows Option should be set to Overlapping Windows not the default value of Tabbed Documents.